# Upgrading Blackboard Learn 9.1 Java issue

Tags: sdk, java, blackboard

I am trying to upgrade Blackboard learn 9.1 to the latest service pack. I have successfully instaslled SP9 and am now trying to install 10, but to do that I've had to install a newer version of JDK. When I changed the JAVA_HOME to reflect this change the installer was reporting that it was still set to the previous version. I restarted the server and now that error has gone, but instead I am getting:

> Java SDK location not found at C:/Java/jdk1.6.0_32.

Can anyone tell me why it is still looking in the path to the old version, and what I can do to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from Blackboard was able to help with this in the end, and the answer is as follows:

If running on Windows, when installing the Java SE Development Kit (JDK), make sure that both the JDK and the JRE components are installed to different locations. Also, ensure that there are no spaces in the path name to either the JDK or the JRE.
Shut down Bb-Services
Install recent version of the Java SE JDK, at least version 7u7
Change the JAVA_Home environment variable

Change the config\bb-config.properteries, changing the paths for bothbbconfig.java.home and bbconfig.java.home.win. Paths need to have forward slashes not the standard Windows backslash.

Comment: It seems that a lot of rich web applications no longer need the entire Java (JDK) framework.  I imagine that Blackboard will be working on a future version that requires less Java support and uses more of the new features in JavaScript.  Its maybe a lot to ask users to install an entire framework like the JDK just to use their application.  It looks like the problem with the backslash is that Blackboard works on both IIS and Apache and some of the configuration files depend on the OS type.  I believe there is a PHP variable like $_SERVER that can tell the instillation what OS type.